# Bindings mode in IBM MQ docker

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to run a java application in bindings mode in IBM MQ docker image, but i am not able to find a proper resource for the same. Do IBM MQ has support for bindings mode in IBM MQ Docker image?

Answer (score 3):

Yes with version limits. If the application is in the same container as the queue manager you can use local bindings to connect them. If they are not then as long as you are using MQ version 9.0.3 or above you can share container namespaces to run the application in a different container than the queue manager.

Source From [this knowledge center page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q114484_.htm) on IBM MQ Container Support:

> You can use namespacing to share the namespaces of the container for the queue manager with other containers, in order to locally bind applications to a queue manager running in separate containers. For more information, see [Running local binding applications in separate containers](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q114488_.htm).